# Unicity of holomorphic functions that agree on real numbers: is this a corollary of the identity theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be two holomorphic functions on some open connected set $D\subset \mathbb{C}$, with $D$ having a non-zero intersection with the real axis (I call $I$ this intersection). Assume that $f=g$ on $I$.

Is it true that this is enough to ensures $f=g$ on $D$? If not, is there any non-trivial condition on $f$ and $g$ that ensures $f=g$ on $D$, given the above constraint?

The reason I think this might be true is by using this improvement of the identity theorem: if $f$ and $g$ agree on a set $S\subset D$ which has an accumulation point $c\in D$, then $f=g$ on $D$.

I am however unable to write down a precise proof (if any). Any illustration with counter-examples (if any) would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a corollary of the identity theorem.

Since $I$ is nonempty, there is some $x\in I$. Since $D$ is open, $I=D\cap \mathbb{R}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. This implies $I$ contains an open interval $I_x$ around $x$. Note $x$ is an accumulation point of $I_x$. Since $f=g$ in this interval $I_x\subset D$ we conclude $f=g$ in $D$.